# Spring MVC send object as @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am following [websystique Spring 4 MVC tutorial](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-restful-web-services-crud-example-resttemplate/) and I am trying to figure out how to send `http` request to match the create user `method`:

```
 //-------------------Create a User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user,    UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName());

        if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
            System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getName() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Or in general how to send a object via `@RequestBody` that match my user object(`POJO`):

```
public class User {

    private String m_name;
    private long m_id;
    private int m_age;
    private int m_salary;

    public User(String name, long id, int age, int salary){
        this.m_name = name;
        this.m_id = id;
        this.m_age = age;
        this.m_salary = salary;
    }
    //getters, setters...
}
```

Comment: The tutorial actually seem to contain multiple ways to do that. There are Postman tool examples, also Java/RestTemplate tests in SpringRestTestClient class..

Comment: Yes, I had missed that part(long hours at the office....). Thanks.